# Analytic function and isolated and accumulation points of a compact set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $E \subset \mathbb{C}$ ($\mathbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers). Let $K \subset E$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Then is it true that

$$f(\mbox{iso}(K)) \cap f(\mbox{acc}(K))= \emptyset? $$

Here $\mbox{iso}(K)$ denotes the set of isolated points of $K$ and $\mbox{acc}(K)$ denotes the set of accumulation points of $K$.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: What if $f$ is constant?

Comment: Yes, remember the answer to "is it true" could be "no"!

Comment: Did you mean $f$ is analytic on some open containing $E$ ? In which case you can set $f$ as you want on the different "connected components" (do you see how to define them)

Comment: is it true if we take f is non constant on connected components of E???